# Keras ImageDataGenerator for multiple inputs and image based target output

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets, tf.keras

I have a model which takes two Images as inputs and generates a single image as a Target output.

All of my training image-data is in the following sub-folders:

- input1
- input2
- target

Can I use the `ImageDataGenerator` class and methods like `flow_from_directory` and `model.fit_generator` method in keras to train the network?

How can I do this? since most examples I have come across deal with single input and a label-based target output.

In my case, I have a non-categorical target output data and multiple inputs.

Please help, as your suggestions can be really helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possibility is to join three `ImageDataGenerator` into one, using `class_mode=None` (so they don't return any target), and using `shuffle=False` (important). Make sure you're using the same `batch_size` for each and make sure each input is in a different dir, and the targets also in a different dir, and that there are exactly the same number of images in each directory.

```
idg1 = ImageDataGenerator(...choose params...)
idg2 = ImageDataGenerator(...choose params...)
idg3 = ImageDataGenerator(...choose params...)

gen1 = idg1.flow_from_directory('input1_dir',
                                shuffle=False,
                                class_mode=None)
gen2 = idg2.flow_from_directory('input2_dir',
                                shuffle=False,
                                class_mode=None)
gen3 = idg3.flow_from_directory('target_dir',
                                shuffle=False,
                                class_mode=None)
```

Create a custom generator:

```
class JoinedGen(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, input_gen1, input_gen2, target_gen):
        self.gen1 = input_gen1
        self.gen2 = input_gen2
        self.gen3 = target_gen

        assert len(input_gen1) == len(input_gen2) == len(target_gen)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.gen1)

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        x1 = self.gen1[i]
        x2 = self.gen2[i]
        y = self.gen3[i]

        return [x1, x2], y

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        self.gen1.on_epoch_end()
        self.gen2.on_epoch_end()
        self.gen3.on_epoch_end()
```

Train with this generator:

```
my_gen = JoinedGen(gen1, gen2, gen3)
model.fit_generator(my_gen, ...)
```

Or create a custom generator. All the structure for it is shown above.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the answer. 
I am currently trying out your solution. I was also thinking along the same line but your class is really useful. However when I run the mode.fit_generator() i get the following warning message for every  image loaded: 
"WARNING:tensorflow:multiprocessing can interact badly with TensorFlow, causing nondeterministic deadlocks. For high performance data pipelines tf.data is recommended."

This seems to be slowing down the training too, it's been over six hours and I haven't been able to see the results from 7000 training images

Comment: I see.... I never saw this error... are you setting `multiprocessing=True` in `fig_generator`? Usually you don't need that. You just need multithreading (the standard), by setting `workers=...`. It will still be parallel loading.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have fixed my problem, after disabling multiprocesssing and your solution worked great.  
How do i call the length method in JoinedGen.__len__() method?

Comment: You need an instance of the generator, in the answer, it's `my_gen`. You can either call `length = len(my_gen)` or you can also `length = my_gen.__length__()`.

Answer (score 4):

The custom class JoinedGen shown in Daniel Möller's post works great if one does not want (or need) to shuffle the training examples. However, more often than not reshuffling at the end of each epoch is highly desirable for the learning process. Fortunately, this can be easily accomplished as well. First, the three `ImageDataGenerators` should use `shuffle = True` (important).

```
idg1 = ImageDataGenerator(...choose params...)
idg2 = ImageDataGenerator(...choose params...)
idg3 = ImageDataGenerator(...choose params...)

gen1 = idg1.flow_from_directory('input1_dir',
                                shuffle=True,
                                class_mode=None)
gen2 = idg2.flow_from_directory('input2_dir',
                                shuffle=True,
                                class_mode=None)
gen3 = idg3.flow_from_directory('target_dir',
                                shuffle=True,
                                class_mode=None)
```

If nothing else is done the three generators will get out of sync after the first epoch since each of them will be reshuffled differently at the end of the first epoch. To make them stay in sync one needs to add two lines at the end of the function `on_epoch_end(self)`. Namely, the last two generators should get the same array of indices as the first generator:

```
class JoinedGen(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, input_gen1, input_gen2, target_gen):
        self.gen1 = input_gen1
        self.gen2 = input_gen2
        self.gen3 = target_gen

        assert len(input_gen1) == len(input_gen2) == len(target_gen)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.gen1)

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        x1 = self.gen1[i]
        x2 = self.gen2[i]
        y = self.gen3[i]

        return [x1, x2], y

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        self.gen1.on_epoch_end()
        self.gen2.on_epoch_end()
        self.gen3.on_epoch_end()
        self.gen2.index_array = self.gen1.index_array
        self.gen3.index_array = self.gen1.index_array
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an external function that handles the whole operation.

```
generator_imgs = ImageDataGenerator(...choose params...)
```

Create the function

```
def generate_generator_multiple(generator):
    gen1 = generator.flow_from_directory('input1_dir', 
                                          shuffle=False, 
                                          class_mode=None,
                                          batch_size=32)

    gen2 = generator.flow_from_directory('input2_dir', 
                                          shuffle=False, 
                                          class_mode=None,
                                          batch_size=32)

    gen3 = generator.flow_from_directory('target_dir', 
                                          shuffle=False, 
                                          class_mode=None,
                                          batch_size=32)
    while True:
        x1 = gen1.next()
        x2 = gen2.next()
        y  = gen3.next()
        
        yield [x1, x2], y
```

Now just call the generation function:

```
my_gen = generate_generator_multiple(generator_imgs)
model.fit_generator(my_gen, ...)
```