# How to enforce paired training in Keras?

Tags: python, image, keras, classification

Is it possible in Keras to include the images with same name in one batch from different classes when using `flow_from_directory`?
How can it be enforced?

Comment: Maybe if you have the same number of images for each dir, this might be automatic provided you pass `shuffle=False`. You can try to plot a few of the images returned, cycle the generator more than one epoch, plot a few again (especially the last batch). If this doesn't work, you can try a parallel approach like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59492866/keras-imagedatagenerator-for-multiple-inputs-and-image-based-target-output/59493865#59493865 --- in the worst case, you will have to create your own custom generator to load images.

Comment: I think you can extend ImageDataGenerator to create your custom generator and the below link can be helpful for you.

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3338